# When I call this function, the program stops

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition

```
int text_input(char pinax[N][M])
{
    char endword[10 +1] = "T*E*L*O*S*";
    int i=0;
    int y=0;
    char word[11];
    while (fgets(word,11,stdin), strcmp(word,endword)) {
        if(strcmp(word,'\0')!=0){
            strcpy(pinax[i++],word);
            y++;
        }
    }

    return y;
}
```

So I try to take as input a string from user and store it in a 2d array pinax[N][M], where N = M = 11 and for some reason it ends when I run it. When I use scanf instead of fgets there is no problem but I prefer fgets so that I can have spaces inside the string. In addition to that, when I print pinax[0](first string of the array) in the case of the fgets method,it prints nothing, which I suspect is the NULL element and when I print pinax[1] which is the second string of the array it prints the first word that the user typed in. Any help is much needed.

Comment: `if(strcmp(word,'\0')!=0)` should at the very least give you a compiler warning

Comment: If you want to test if `word` is not empty use `if (word[0] != 0)`

Comment: Why do you have both `fgets()` and `strcmp(word, endword)` in the `while` condition? If you want to test both results you need to combine them with `&&`, not `,`

Comment: The line `while (fgets(word,11,stdin), strcmp(word,endword)) {` ignores the EOF condition reported by `fgets()` as `NULL` — which is dubious at best and probably just plain wrong.  You can't afford to ignore EOF.  The computer can count better than you can — use just `char endword[] = "T*E*L*O*S*";`.  And the `11` in `fgets(word,11,stdin)` should be `sizeof(word)` for the same reason.  And 11 isn't long enough to hold `T*E*L*O*S*` plus a newline plus a null byte.

Answer (score 3):

This call of `strcmp`

```
if(strcmp(word,'\0')!=0){
```

invokes undefined behavior. The function expects two pointers but the second argument in the call is a character that is converted to a null pointer.

As for your problem with the empty first string then it is the result of the presence in the input buffer the new line character `'\n'` of a preceding input.

To avoid the problem you can use the function `scanf`. For example

```
int text_input( char pinax[N][M] )
{
    const char endword[10 +1] = "T*E*L*O*S*";
    int i = 0;

    char word[11];

    while ( i < N && scanf( " %10[^\n]", word ) == 1 && strcmp( word,endword ) != 0 ) 
    {
        strcpy( pinax[i++], word );
    }

    return i;
}
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Comment: Ok  but I have one more problem as far as finding the sum of all the characters in the 2d array included he spaces. How can I do that

Comment: @Liqdream03 One problem is one question. You should ask a new question if you have other problems.

Comment: Technically, the second parameter to `strcmp()` is a weirdly-written null pointer.  In C (but not C++), `'\0'` is an integer constant 0, and that will be converted by the prototype into a null pointer.  Passing null pointers to `strcmp()` is not a recipe for happiness.